# How to setThreadContextInheritable(true) via xml on Spring's dispatcherportlet and dispatcherservlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc, requestcontext

I want to make the current request available to child threads without passing on the original request as method parameters through several layers. The application runs both as a servlet and as a portlet.

Normally, DispatcherServlet and DispatcherPortlet set the current request into a RequestContextHolder on the current thread. That way, a call thread has access to the current request. The request is not propagated to child threads.

In my case, the request spawns a subthread where it makes a ReST call using RestTemplate, and I need to access the original request in an ClientHttpRequestInterceptor that intercepts the RestTemplate. The request that is passed to intercept is useless, I need the original request that hit the server.

Both DispatcherServlet and DispatcherPortlet have a feature to pass on the RequestContext to child threads: setThreadContextInheritable(true). However, it seems not so easy to set that flag to true. There is no init-param which sets it, and usually you specify them in web.xml or portlet.xml.

Is there a way to customize a dispatcher portlet or servlet via their setters using xml configuration? The only way I found is to write a custom dispatcherservlet/portlet which sets the flag to true internally and use that in web.xml and portlet.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly through XML configuration. You would need to do as you said and create a subclass of `DispatcherServlet` which internally calls `setThreadContextInheritable(true)`.

The alternative is to perform your `ServletContext` configuration in Java. Spring provides a [`WebApplicationInitializer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) and a number of useful subtypes where you can register a customized `DispatcherServlet` (other servlets and filters).

You'd create your instance.

```
DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
servlet.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
```

and then register it

```
ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", servlet);
```

Comment: Is Java config possible for DispatcherPortlet, too?